# $substr doesnt work on mongodb compass community

Tags: sql, mongodb

[image]

I have a collection and i want to show like some characteres from "categoria" which is inside "Problema", but it keeps giving me this error, and i have searched alot and i think everything is correct, any help?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use $substr you will need to use an [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/)

I tried the aggregation tool in Compass, but it is not clear to me.

However, I tried this aggregation with one collection:

```
db.getCollection('products').aggregate(
[
    {
        $project: 
        {
            tex: { $substr: ["$name",2,7] }
        }
    }
])
```

[image]

Comment: I went to "Aggregations"  in Mongo between "Documents" and "Explain Plan" and pasted this : db.getCollection('alunos').aggregate(
[
    {
        $project: 
        {
            tex: { $substr: ["$Nome",0,5] }
        }
    }
])                                                          And nothing happened